# Postgresql: created a temporary table to find and delete repeated rows and I am not able to delete due to relation error

Tags: postgresql

```
WITH RowNumCTE AS (
SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    PARTITION BY parcelid, property_address, saleprice, saledate, legal_ref
ORDER BY
    unique_id) AS row_num
FROM housing)

DELETE
FROM RowNumCTE
WHERE row_num > 1
```

I am able to access the RowNumCTE table, but for some reason am not able to delete from it

Answer (score 0):

The contents of a CTE it not a temporary table, but **the result set of a query**. As such you cannot apply DML to it. You can achieve by moving your row_num condition into the CTE itself.

```
with RowNumCte as (
     ( select parcelid, property_address, saleprice, saledate, legal_ref -- ... column list
         from (
                select h.*  
                      , row_number() 
                           over( partition by parcelid, property_address, saleprice, saledate, legal_ref
                                     order by unique_id
                               ) as row_num
                   from housing h
               )
        where row_num = 1 
     ) 
select * 
  from RowNumCte ;
```